# What can i do to address a parent in lua?

Tags: lua, love2d, class-hierarchy

I am making a game, and in it the player needs to spawn some bullets:

```
game
├──player = {}
└──bullets = {}
```

I've heard in godot you can use `parent` to address the parent node and wonder if i can imitate that somehow.

I currently have 2 potential solutions:

```
local game = {
    player = player.new(x, y, spawnBullet),
    bullets = {}
}
```

`spawnBullet` being a function. Although that would require doing that for all functions, which might be annoying.

My second solution would be to pass game iteslf to the player

```
local game
game = {
    player = player.new(x, y, game),
    bullets = {},
```

And in `player.new(x, y, parent)`

```
player.parent = parent
```

Are these solutions all there is available or are there better ones?

Whatever, I made a node module myself.

```lua
local node = {}
node.__index = node

local new = function(name, parent)
    assert(name, "Please provide a name for the node")
    local newNode = {
        name = name,
        parent = parent,
    }
    return setmetatable(newNode, node)
end

return setmetatable(
    {
        new = new,
        __call = new,
    },
    node
)
```

Answer (score 0):

are you using an engine/framework?

I am using gideros and I do it this way, example:

main game

-- myplayer

-- bullets

In my player class:

```
-- SHOOT
if self.isspace then
    local bullet = Character_Bullet.new(self.world, ...)
    self:getParent():addChild(bullet)
    self.isspace = false
end
```

Comment: I'm using love2d, and i'm asking about how i can _simulate_ the behaviour of `getParent()` with table hierarchies and if it's possible at all

Comment: well, I have looked for getparent for love2d and it is not straight forward. You may add a bullet table to your player. Something like player.bullet = bullet.